# Dropdown with virtual scroll and LazyLoading [Help]

Tags: angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, dropdown, lazy-loading

I have been learning angular for a couple of days now and i decided i want to make a dropdown element using PrimeNg and i want it to have virtual scroll, lazy loading and a search bar. I want to make it so at the start lets say we have 1000 elements and it loads the first 100 then when the user scrolls down past the 100 it loads the next 100 and so on. Im using PrimeNg Version ^14.2.3

My question is why doesn't the loadDropdownCities() method work and how am i supposed to do it?
I think the problem is in the slice, because maybe the `event.rows` and `event.first` are undefined but honestly i have no idea how to fix it.

Here is the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CityService} from "../../services/city.service";
import {City} from "../../common/City";
import {ConfirmationService, LazyLoadEvent, MessageService} from "primeng/api";
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-city',
  templateUrl: './city.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./city.component.scss']
})
export class CityComponent implements OnInit {

  city: City = new City;
  cities: City[] = [];
  dropdownCities: City[] = [];
  totalRecords: number = 0;
  loading: boolean = false;
  cityDialog: boolean = false;
  submitted: boolean = false;


  constructor(private cityService: CityService,private messageService: MessageService, private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) {  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    
  }

  loadDropdownCities(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
    this.loading = true;
    let first = event.first ?? 0;
    let rows = event.rows ?? 100;
      this.cityService.getCity().then(res => {
        this.dropdownCities = res.slice(first, rows + first);
        first += 100;
        this.totalRecords = res.length;
        this.loading = false;
      })
  }
```

```
<p-dropdown
      [options]="dropdownCities"
      optionLabel="name"
      [filter]="true"
      filterBy="name"
      [showClear]="true"
      placeholder="Select a City"
      [virtualScroll]="true"
      [itemSize]="31"
      [lazy]="true"
      (onLazyLoad)="loadDropdownCities($event)"
    >
      <ng-template pTemplate="loader" let-city>
        <div class="city-item">
          <div>{{ city.name }}</div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </p-dropdown>
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {City} from "../common/City";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CityService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCity() {
    return this.http.get<any>('assets/city.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => <City[]>res.data)
      .then(data => { return data; });
  }
}
```

```
export class City {
  public cityId: number = 0;
  public name: string = "";
  public code: string = "";
  public county: County = new County();
}
```

Comment: What even is `event`? Where is it defined? There is no `event` parameter, and even if you have it as a field, you must access it using `this.`. What's the deal with it?

Comment: You are calling `loadDropdownCities` from the template without passing the event parameter. You can start by changing that to `(onLazyLoad)="loadDropdownCities($event)"`.

Comment: yea I changed it, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I had done that originally but i deleted it accidentally sooo No it doesn't work.